# Troubleshooting Packet Loss in my Home Network

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, packet-loss

I have a DSL subscription in my apartment and I want to connect a second apartment of mine in the same building. Here's the setup:

I have a wireless ADSL router that was provided by the ISP: Technicolor TG582n (`192.168.1.254`). An ethernet cable goes from the router of this apartment to the router of the second one. Its length is between 20 and 25 meters.

In the second apartment, I have a wireless router. Linksys E900. This one I bought not so long ago. This router was set in *bridged* mode.

I didn't set up the network personally. My brother who set up the network said that the Internet connection from the second apartment is "working really good", before I get to live there. He even played some kind of MMORPG with a couple of friends with no issues.

However, I only encountered issues in the second apartment. I noticed that the connection takes ages to be established, while it's normal in the first apartment. Everything was slow. Browsing was very very difficult.

I ran a a ping from my laptop in the second apartment to the Technicolor router, and I noticed that I had a lot of *lost packets* (between 35% and 65%). Packets that are not dropped had very very low latency (between 2 and 3 ms). Packets get lost even more if I ping with greater payload (1k for example).

I unplugged the ethernet cable from the Linksys and plugged it in my laptop. No packet loss, no latency, everything is smooth. I am not a networking guy, but I thought `well maybe because it's in bridged mode`, so I changed the settings of Linksys to act as a normal router: IP: `192.168.2.1`, subnet `255.255.255.0`, and its default gateway is the Technicolor (`192.168.1.254`).

I connected my laptop to the Linksys through Wi-Fi again, and the problem is still there. Now I thought it may be a wireless issue, so I connected my laptop to the Linksys with an ethernet cable. No success.

I used another router (an old D-Link; maybe the router itself is not good?), and no success too.

I took the Linksys to the first apartment and plugged it to the Technicolor with a short cable. I plugged my laptop to the Linksys and the problem went away. There is no packet loss.

This is very puzzling: 
1- My tests (especially the last one) show that there is an issue with the cable going from the first apartment to the second one: it could be too long, defected, or there is an interference somewhere.
2- When I plug this very cable to my laptop directly, I have no issues.

Is there anything I missed? How can further pinpoint the issue? Why is it working normally when directly connected to a PC but not when I use a router in the middle?

Comment: It could be that the Linksys's WAN port isn't as good as your PC's Ethernet port.

Comment: How can I test that ?